# Shuffle ArrayList without random number

Tags: java, algorithm, random, arraylist

Hi I want to shuffle my ArrayList without Random Number generator but only one random number can be used . Is there any way to do this ?

The algorithm should be based on the following:

- size of ArrayList (non zero)
- index of each items in ArrayList
- Random number (cant generate inside loop, only one random number can be generated)

**example**

```
    int randomNumber = new Random(10).nextInt();
    myList = shuffle(myList, randomNumber)

    public ArrayList<> shuffle(ArrayList<> myList, int randomNumber){
      for(int index = 0 ; index < myList.size() ; index++ ){
       //shuffle algorithm working
      }
    return myList;
    }
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you have to do your home work assignment yourself

Comment: @wblaschko :D not like that, I am looking for idea to reach the solution

Comment: hint : you can use this `Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j);`

Comment: ^ this is the correct way to go about this.

Comment: Collections.swap(List<?> list, int i, int j); does not touch my requirment

Comment: You can't use `randomNumber` as a seed to generate your own stream of random numbers in the function? For example: `randomNumber = (randomNumber * 214013) + 2531011;`

Comment: @Blastfurnace the final outcome of this problem is whenever the randomNumber is same the order of shuffling should be same. thats why I'm insisting to not use random numbers.

Comment: That's not a problem if you generate your own random numbers from a given seed value. Multiple runs from the same starting point should produce identical results. Combine a [linear congruential generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) with a [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) and you have a solution. Note: I just picked a LCG because it's simple to implement.

Comment: @Blastfurnace suppose  the function calls more than once with the same ArrayList. (with the original list (reseted list)) then the order would have been changed right ? if the shuffling is based on one random number that creates only once in the application life cycle, then the order will be same always.

Comment: @devrob: If you need to keep the original ArrayList then you would shuffle a copy of the ArrayList instead. Each time you shuffle a new copy of the original with the same starting seed it would produce the same randomized result.

Comment: Check this [link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shuffle-a-given-array/) out. I hope it'll answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contrary to your thinking, pseudo-random numbers are deterministic. From the same seed, you always get the same sequence. Just use the value of randomNumber to initialize the generator.

Actually, arithmetic is absolutely unable to generate true randomness.

Comment: True randomness can be approached by monitoring factors external to your program, such as wall clock time or system activity (number of running processes, reserved memory, I/O count...)